# Got "Failed to copy artifacts from another project with filter: **/*.war" while copying the war file from another project

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Initially i used below configuration and job failed

[image: This job failed with below configuration]

It gave below error message

[image: error it gave]

It worked with below configuration

[image: configuration with which it worked]

So basically when i changed "***Which build***" option from "***Latest successful build***" to "***Copy from WORKSPACE of latest completed build***" it worked .

Can some please help me understand what it the difference between "Latest successful build" and "Copy from WORKSPACE of latest completed build" options.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the first (source) project, you will need to add a post-build step to Archive the artifact, otherwise, they will not be archived and the destination project won't be able to find them under the "artifact" folder.

Comment: Nice! Would be nice for the 'copy artifact' plugin to mention that heh

Answer (score 2):

Hi I had the same problem:

```
ERROR: Failed to copy artifacts from package with filter: **/*.war
[DeployPublisher][INFO] Build failed, project not deployed
Finished: FAILURE
```

AND the solution was:

```
Config Project > Copy artifacts from another project > Which build > select the option: " Copy from WORKSPACE of latest completed build"
```

Comment: This seems to work for me.  I wonder if there's a gotcha that will bite me because I'm not using proper artifacts??

Comment: this doesn't work if the file is not archived as @Ahmad Mohammad said